# Scripting - Proportional edit mesh

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine

I want to move a polygone using its 4 vertices. I get the MeshProxy of that vertex then I change its XYZ positions. The problem is that it separates the whole polygone from the object. I want to obtain a smooth deformation (proportional edit as in edit mode). How can I do that in BGE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Smooth Shading.**

A look at the docs [`bge.types.KX_MeshProxy`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html#bge.types.KX_MeshProxy) reveals that

> Vertices will be split by face if necessary. Vertices can only be
>   shared between faces if:
>
> 1. They are at the same position
> 2. UV coordinates are the same
> 3. Their normals are the same (both polygons are “Set Smooth”)
> 4. They are the same color, for example: a cube has 24 vertices: 6 faces with 4 vertices per face

Smooth shading will stop the face separating from the mesh. Un-comment the lines marked with `#SS` in script below to test.

**Pseudo linear falloff on a sphere.**

Test script, on sensor event selects a random face, calculates the face center, finds all verts within a distance of that face center (arbitrary hardcoded `0.4`) and moves them away using the face center vector.  (Using a sphere to test where the origin is centroid, so any local point on surface is also a radial vector (normal))

A vert at the center of the face can be moved the maximum (`1.1`) units away falling off linearly to zero for verts on or outside `0.4` from calculated center of face.

```
from mathutils import Vector
from random import randint

def deform(cont):
    ob = cont.owner

    if not cont.sensors["Mouse"].positive:
        return None

    mesh = ob.meshes[0]
    poly = mesh.getPolygon(randint(0, mesh.numPolygons - 1))
    material_index = poly.getMaterialIndex()
    # find center of poly
    cent = Vector()
    n = poly.getNumVertex()
    for i in range(n):
        v = mesh.getVertex(material_index, getattr(poly, "v%d" % (i + 1)))
        cent += v.XYZ
        v.color = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0] # juicy yellow head.
        #v.XYZ *= 1.1 #SS
    cent /= n
    #return # SS
    # get all the verts within 0.4 radius of cent
    for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(material_index)):
         v = mesh.getVertex(material_index, v_index)
         d = (v.XYZ - cent)
         if d.length <= 0.4:
             v.XYZ += 1.1 / 0.4 * (0.4 - d.length) * cent.normalized()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can save the modified object to .obj file @batFINGER ?

Comment: from the game engine?

Comment: yes from the game engine after I deformed the shape?

Comment: Also, How can I define and apply a force that will not deform the shape continuously at every frame, but instead apply it once?